# How to Remove duplicate result body in struts2

Tags: configuration, struts2

I have a global result that returns a 404 error to the user.
I also have a default action that I would like to do the same thing.

I would like my success result in the default action to extend my global `notfound` result, but I don't see how to. Am I missing something?

```xml
    <default-action-ref name="notfound" />

    <global-results>
        <result name="notfound" type="httpheader">
           <param name="error">404</param>
           <param name="errorMessage">Oh No You Didn't</param>
        </result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="com.me.s2ui.AccessException" result="notfound" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

    <action name="notfound">
        <result type="httpheader">
           <param name="error">404</param>
           <param name="errorMessage">Oh No You Didn't</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Comment: When/How do you use this action? Why not just return `notfound` as a result from action?

Comment: @AleksandrM I have the notfound configured as the default action to catch any random url coming into my app. I don't have any implementation code with which to return the notfound result. I am just using default behavior.

Comment: No *direct* way. But you can just create simple action class and return your result from it. You can also use unknown handlers to handle unknown actions.

Comment: @Aaron There's not such thing in Struts2 as extending result, you can extend the result type class. Create an interceptor which returns `notfound` result if the action name is `notfound`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [@Aleksandr M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1700321/aleksandr-m) and [@Roman C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/573032/roman-c) in the comments, what I wanted was not possible. After posting the question I realized I wanted logging in the default action, so I ended up writing a class.

```java
@org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action("notfound")
public class DefaultAction implements Action, ServletRequestAware
{
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DefaultAction.class);
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception
{
    logger.warn("Unknown target "+request.getRequestURI());
    return "securityerror";
}

@Override
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest req)
{
    this.request = req;
}
}
```

Struts.xml

```xml
    <default-action-ref name="notfound" />

    <global-results>
        <result name="intLogin" type="redirect">${#request.loginUrl}</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">user</result>
        <result name="securityerror" type="httpheader">
           <param name="error">404</param>
           <param name="errorMessage">Oh No You Didn't</param>
        </result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="com.me.s2ui.AccessException" result="securityerror" />
    </global-exception-mappings>
```

Comment: :) I almost typed "maybe you want to do some logging also" in my previous comment. +1 for answering your own question and accepting it.